# What does E9 at the end of casted string to double value means ?

Tags: java, numbers, double

I am doing some simple programming task just to keep up and understand some tricky and hidden stuff. 
Here is this program:

```
String numbersArray = "1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005";
String[] stringNumbers = numbersArray.split(" ");
double sum = 0;

for (String s : stringNumbers) {

    try {

        double number = Double.valueOf(s);
        sum += number;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Unable to cast " + s + " to double!");

    }

}
System.out.println(sum);
```

When I debug the - put break point on `sum+=number;`
the debugger show something like

```
number = 1.000000001E9
```

and when I print out the result it is

```
5.000000015E9
```

So what `E9` mean and why there is a dot `"."` before the last number ?

Comment: `E9` means 10^9 in scientific notation. so `1.000000001E9 ` is `1000000001 `.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: E9 means 10^9 (as in scientific notation)

Answer (score 3):

That(`5.000000015E9`) is the [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for writing the numbers. So E9 would be 10^9.

Answer (score 2):

`E` is the scientific notation for the number to represent the `power` and digit followed by e is the actual power of that number. Check the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29).

> if m is less than 10 power **-3** or greater than or equal to 10 power **7**, then it is
>   represented in so-called "**computerized scientific notation**." Let n be
>   the unique integer such that 10n ≤ m < 10n+1; then let a be the
>   mathematically exact quotient of m and 10n so that 1 ≤ a < 10